# What is the difference between the following sentences in this context?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

If I want to ask my friend if a school work that we are doing belongs to a specific school subject which of the following sentences should I use:

> 1 does that work have to do with that subject?
>
> 2 is that work related with that subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call "a school work" an "assignment" to be idiomatic. Here are some possible expressions:
"What subject is this assignment for?"
"What course is this assignment for?"
"Which subject is this assignment in?"

If someone has already mentioned an assignment, and you want to ask which course it's for, you might just ask:
"For what course?"

If you want to sound very stiff and formal, you could say:
"For what course is this work assigned?"